# Binary data not printing correctly

Tags: c, printf, binary-data

I am trying to print binary data and it is coming out as long hex strings even though I am using the `%02x` format specifier which I thought was just supposed to output a single byte (2 hex digits). Here is the code (**line 79** is the problem):

```
void ReadFile( char *name ){
     FILE *file;
     FILE *fOutput;
     char *buffer;
     unsigned long fileLen;
     //Open ORF file
     file = fopen( name, "rb" );
     if( !file ){
        fprintf( stderr, "Unable to open file %s", name );
        return;
     }

     // Open output file
     fOutput = fopen( "orf_dump", "wb" );
     if( ! fOutput ){
         fprintf( stderr, "Unable to open output file %s", "orf_dump" );
         return;
     }

     //Get file length
     fseek( file, 0, SEEK_END );
     fileLen=ftell( file );
     fseek( file, 0, SEEK_SET );

     //Allocate memory
     buffer = (char *)malloc( fileLen + 1 );
     if( !buffer ){
         fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");
         fclose(file);
         return;
     }

     //Read file contents into buffer
     fread( buffer, fileLen, 1, file );
     fclose(file);

      //Do what ever with buffer
     int xBuffer = 30000;
     for( ; xBuffer < 30100; xBuffer++ ){
         printf( "%02x ", buffer[ xBuffer ] ); // Problematic line (79)
         fwrite( buffer + xBuffer, 1, 1, fOutput );
     }
     printf( "\n" );
     free(buffer);
 }
```

When I use hexdump to dump the output file, it looks correct:

```
hexdump orf_dump
0000000 3477 d52f 63fe e57f 0af9 d471 c981 e7e0
0000010 1fd3 8cc5 03f6 758c 98e6 0f77 4942 a607
0000020 e340 989e 9ec2 f784 b93d dfe0 fcf0 c21d
0000030 00ff fc97 c80f f94e 7720 f5c9 3dc8 e908
0000040 a7cf 3ebf 618d 9391 c186 b81d 1d03 dc71
0000050 9d0e 1d01 2789 0834 c956 79e8 3afd ede4
0000060 803e 73fb
0000064
```

Comment: please show an example of what is printed.

Comment: You need to use `unsigned char` as your buffer type, or cast individual elements to `unsigned char` before printing. You also don't need to add 1 to file length for allocation.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is the expected output and what is the actual output?

Answer (score 2):

Sub-int-sized values are promoted when passed (`char x=42; printf("%d", x)` passes `x` as an int). If you promote a negative signed value, it is sign-extended (e.g. a signed char `0xf0` gets extended to `0xfffffff0`).

Width in `printf` (the `2` in your `%02x`) is the minimum width. If the value doesn't fit in that many characters, more are used. If you want to print a single byte, you need to extract only the byte you want to print (e.g. via `val & 0xff`), or avoid sign-extension by starting with an unsigned value.